# Should i use field.tpl.php or Display suite to add my own classes to fields?

Tags: entities, theming

I want to get rid of the default classes and add my own to the fields. I was always using field.tpl.php but i've read some tutorials where people are doing this with Display Suite. So should i do this via field.tpl.php or Display suite?

Comment: I'ld stay with field.tpl.php in that case if it's only on markup level, since this is code you can work with outside the database. That may be much easier maintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's matter of opinion, really. I'm using DS and it works fine, but it might have disadvantages later on, because I will have to export my settings to code with Features.

Also, DS isn't your only option - you can also try:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/semantic_fields
- https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class

and others. Which depends on your other needs - for example, are you planning to use DS multiple display modes handling?

Comment: +1! Also it might be a big overload if it's only for cleaning markup.

Comment: No, i just need to wrap fields in DIVs my own way, add wrapper sometimes so i think the .tpl.php method is the best one for me. Thanks for your help!